# Convert each frame from a MovieClip to cached BitmapData to another MC while running in real time

Tags: actionscript-3, caching

So Im creating a "something" and it was done..... until the moment I tested it on my hardest difficulty ..... then things got slow, really really slow -> like 10-20 fps slow (from 40-50fps in easy mode).

*What is this "something" about* :

there is this **Main** MovieClip with 420x312 dimension with like 15-20 frames in it. After I click it, I dynamically create 16 **little** MCs, each with 1/16 of the dimension of the **Main** MC (26px X 19.5px) and copyPixels area from the **Main** MC to the **little** MCs on EVERY FRAME while the "project" is running(each **little** MC has a different area that is being copied from the **Main** MC, so when put together, the 16 make an exact copy of the **Main**).
The problem is that doing this is very costly on the performance(at this scale (dimensions an MCs to copyPixels to)).

*The Solutions (or the way I think it would have to be solved):

I need to do do exactly the same- to create 16 MCs to copy portions from the **Main** to them, but not to do this on EVERY Frame, rather to do that only ONCE and after that to save it/cache it to the memory. And after all that to take them from the memory and to put them on the sage, and to do whatever I want after that.

To sum up my Question:

How do I create a new MC that has the same visual data(content) and length(frames) from another MC and store the new MC ( or maybe it is described better as **preload/pre-cache/cache** ). I do know that this(the whole process of converting and creating new MC from the old one) will take some time before I can use/put it on the stage(like 1-10 secs, depending on the machine it is running on).

Any code/links/references to this will useful.

Comment: not updating every frame seems like a good idea. In games I've made with mini maps I've had to update only parts of the mini map every frame to stop my mini-map slowing performance of the whole game.

Comment: well yes I did come to the same conclusion, any ideas on how to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, creating multiple-framed MCs via code is not supported in Flash (there's no code to manage frames of a `new MovieClip()`). However, you are able to use this kind of technology to produce a "fake" MC containig a `Sprite`, an embedded `Bitmap` object, an array of `BitmapData` objects and a `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener that changes the displayed bitmap data. An example:

```
    public class AnimatedSprite extends Sprite 
{
    private static var _sequence:Vector.<BitmapData>; // contains animations
    private static var _initialized:Boolean = false;
    protected var _currentFrame:int;
    private var _playing:Boolean;
    protected var _base:Bitmap; // an object that will be drawn at frame change
    protected function initialize():void {
        if (_initialized) return;
        _sequence = new Vector.<BitmapData>();
        // stuff your _sequence with proper bitmaps here
        // note the method is called only once
        _initialized = true;
    }

    public function AnimatedSprite() 
    {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialize(); 
        }
        if (!_sequence[0]) {
            throw new UninitializedError('Class ' + Object(this).constructor + ' is designed wrongly, a bitmap array MUST have a non-null at 0th position!');
        }
        _currentFrame = 0;
        _playing = false;
        _base = new Bitmap(_sequence[0]);
        addChild(_base);
        // cacheAsBitmap = true; wrong move!
    }
    private function displayBitmap(prev:Boolean = false):void 
    {
        if (_sequence[_currentFrame]) {
            _base.bitmapData = _sequence[_currentFrame]; // no longer drawing, but assigning instead
            // for some reason, copyPixels is not for this, but if using a stored seq, this ROCKS. JUST ROCKS.
            return;
        }
        if (prev) {
            // forced search of a bitmap. Designing this to be "true" if called from goto* or if looping
            var i:int = _currentFrame-1; // if we're here, there's no bitmap at current frame, there's a null
            while (!_sequence[i]) i--; // must have at least one bitmap prior to this, or else throwing error at constructor
            _base.bitmapData = _sequence[i];
        }
    }
    // rest of functions skipped
}
```

The enter frame listener is skipped in here, but can be easily created from the concept. Just call `displayBitmap()` if changing `_currentFrame`. Control functions are skipped too.

Using this, you create one full scale copy of your `Main`, provided it doesn't change, and display the appropriate frame whenever you need it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Well somehow Im not getting what you are telling me. I suppose that you suggest that i should 1st put all the bitmapData in the **sequence**, then set an ENTER_FRAME event and in there call `displayBitmap`, but how do i use it /when do i set the **prev** = true ???/.,.,.,.,.,can you include some more code cause there are things unclear for me.

Comment: I tried:(dont know if its close to what you are suggesting or not(cause i dont quite get your method) ): get the Moving MC.Start to loop through all its frames. Store the data (lets say from the top left corner )from every single frame into a Vector.Then create a new bitmap and give it the whole bitmaps that are showing that topLeft corner(from the vector).After that I use an ENTER FRAME event and in there i do this: `currentPuzzleElement.setChildIndex( currentPuzzleElement.geChildAt(0), currentPuzzleElement.numChildren - 1)

Comment: where **CurrentPuzzleEmenets** is actually the bitmap where I put the bitmaps from the vector.

And this method actually works fine until your Moving MC has more then 30-40 frames. If we add more Frames to the Moving MC the FPS starts to drop fast

Comment: somehow i figured it out and most of the staff i used was from your code. So thanks alot.

Comment: Hmm. The sample `ENTER_FRAME` listener is as dumb as this: `function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void { _currentFrame++; if (_currentFrame>=_sequence.length) _currentFrame=0; displayBitmap(); }` and setting `prev` to true is only required if you make a `gotoAndPlay()` into such a sprite, then you set `_currentFrame` to the frame supplied and call `displayBitmap(true)` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could run 16 copies of that mc and apply a mask on them, but why making it simple when you can make it very slow and complicated.

Comment: before time I did try your suggestion but didnt work. Yet after you suggested it again I forced myself to try it out, the outcome -> somehow it is slower then even using **copyPixel** idk why but it is slower. Currently Im trying to do it with GreenSock BlitMask, but when masking, the whole masked movieClip stops playing. Im trying to figure out why and how to solve this. So its not working with your suggestion. But thanks anyway

Comment: Well now i know - > you cant use GreenSock BlitMask, its only for statick Objects. So the masking solution doesnt solve the problem, atleast in this scenario.

Comment: @GregorII Apparently GreenSocket BitMask sets `cacheAsBitmap` property to true, this prevents Flash from updating the object if its contents are changes in any way.